# Duplicated labels on tile boundaries

Tags: mapbox

I'm using MapBox Studio.
I've converted a layer to text in order to display labels but duplicate labels are displaying for each tile boundary.
Is there any way to display a single, roughly-centered label using the functionality available in MapBox Studio?

[MapBox duplicated labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzWS7.jpg)

One suggestion was to create point geometries and use that as the source but I'm not sure if that's possible using MapBox Studio?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please post the code you have written so far and have a look at this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out how to do this using points in geojson, e.g.

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Name": "Inhumbane Province"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      34.304783,
      -22.90156
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  }
}
```

I add this as a dataset and then convert to a tileset.

Just need to add points for all required locations.